# Getting 500 error when starting IIS Express localhost (500.19)

Tags: iis, localhost, visual-studio-2019

Ive got a project which i run on my main computer, everything works fine there. Then i also want to use that project on my laptop, so i get the code via git from azure devops, build the project and everything shows up as working. As soon as i want to run the project, either via npm start or via visual studio 2019, i get a 500 error displayed in the browser, like really quick.

And i get zero error codes or messages, the only push in the right direction is that the cmd that displays the status of IIS, displays 500.19, but thats it. I have no idea what this might be since it doesnt show any errors?

It is installed on a fresh computer, we tried installing this on another computer and it worked there, but not on my computer.

Ive tried numerous things, such as reinstalling IIS Express, editing / removing applicationHost.config, editing web.config, checking access rights for all the files and folders.

**Possible solution?:**

According to my project on my other pc and the internet there should be an applicationhost.config in .vs/config/****, which it doesnt for me? which may be a problem? i dont know to be honest, i have been stuck on this problems for a couple of days now..

Comment: Show the actual error page please. If it was 0x8007000d, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: the error page was just the standard chrome 500 page, no errors at all